# Displaying correct joomla website information when posting website link

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I was hoping someone can help me fix an issue. When someone posts a link to my joomla created website, they get the heading "Whats New?", which is my default article page for the site. It is the current blog articles written.

For example, if someone posted my link on facebook, it would look like this:

```
Whats New? 
MyDomain.com
Description of website goes here...
```

Everything looks great except for the "Whats New?".  Is there a way to put My webpage name instead of the name of the default page? How about showing an image? When posted on facebook, there is just text and no image used.

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook uses Opengraph** data to build those posts. If facebook isn't offered OpenGraph data, then it will use its own methods to try and find the information it needs. Sometimes with useless results. There are a lot of options to fix this. Joomla extensions has a few opengraph extensions for you to install, some of those should work fine. You can always write something yourself or add the data in your template. But don't expect results right away, because facebook caches those media objects for some time.

- *Open graph:* https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
- *Joomla Extensions:* http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/open-graph

There are more ways to fix this, but this is probably the easiest for you. Hope it helps.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla backend, do the following:

1. Open the menu item the the article is assigned to.
2. On the right hand side, open the **Page Display Options** panel
3. Add whatever you like to the **Browser Page Title** parameter.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried both the Browse Page Title and the Page Heading title, and neither of them worked. i still get "Whats New"?